# Is it possible to run browser from USB Flash Drive on locked down computer?

Tags: flash

I'm considering making a Flex/AS3 based web application but worrying about some employers (i.e. potential customers) that don't have access to Flash plug in version 9 and up. Why? Maybe their corporate standard for browser is old; maybe they lock down employees computers which prevents users to download and install the plug-in or an alternate browser; maybe Flash's ubiquity goes away in the next 3 years given Adobe's recent announcements; etc.

Anyway, my question is, would it be possible to insert a USB Flash drive into the client computer in question and run a Browser having flash (e.g. chrome) on the USB drive (assuming such a browser has already been installed on the USB drive), to access the web application with full functionality? I'm just trying to think of workarounds if my customer doesn't have flash plug-in and can't download to install it.

Comment: If the company is paranoid enough to block Flash, they probably also block other ways of getting Flash.  Many companies completely disable USB ports.

Comment: I would suggest making executables which package the necessary flash runtimes (exe/app)

Comment: If the computer is locked down, how would the user run the executable on his/her machine? Not sure I follow.

Comment: Try to embed flash player in the application using the f-in-box or flajector. It must help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox for example has portable version that is fully functional, and can be installed to usb. Actually as far as i can remember, there is no any install, but only one exe file.

Check it out:

http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable